# File path image directory

Tags: php, html, content-management-system

My site displays articles, and some of them include many images (hundreds).

The content field in MYSQL contain HTML tags like `<img  src=../dir1…./name1.jpg…etc -`
This gives me the ability to display images in the two systems (site, CMS)

My directory hierarchy:

```
Myproject (root)
-Site files
       o Config
       o Include
       o Js     
       o ...
-CMS files (admin)
-Images (tree)
```

How can I save image **file path** (dynamically - not absolute), if I change the location of any directory (CMS, Site or Images), and still view the images in the site and the CMS system?

Comment: What is wrong with using an absolute path? I've found that to be by far the most reliable way to link to resources in a dynamic site.

Answer (score 0):

if you use an HTML Editor in your CMS, you can set a base address for your site, and < img > tags will save correctly in editor and shown correctly in your site. I'd recommend [CKEDITOR](http://ckeditor.com) to you. just set config.baseHref='YOUR ROOT ADDRESS'; in config.js file.